# How to convert sqlalchemy automap query result to json?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I already have database with tables that represent json-reply model

I am using Base = automap_base() to create my classes like this

```
import simplejson as json
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import QueryableAttribute


Base = automap_base()

# engine, suppose it has two tables 'user' and 'address' set up
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://test:test@localhost/test")

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

session = Session(engine)
Person = Base.classes.person

persons = session.query(Person).all()
for person in persons:
    print (person.name)

s = json.dumps([dict(r) for r in persons.values()])
```

And i have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rusagm/pythonProjects/sqlalchemytest/send.py", line 24, in <module>
    s = json.dumps([dict(r) for r in persons])
  File "c:/Users/rusagm/pythonProjects/sqlalchemytest/send.py", line 24, in <listcomp>
    s = json.dumps([dict(r) for r in persons])
TypeError: 'person' object is not iterable
```

I want to create json from my sqlalchemy automapped query. What should i do?

Comment: Load the query response into a `pandas` dataframe and then save to json with `df.to_json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially do something like:

```
import json
from bson import json_util
json.dumps([{i:v for i, v in r.__dict__.items() if i in r.__table__.columns.keys()} for r in persons], default=json_util.default)
```

But as suggested, a pandas dataframe to_json would be better.

Comment: How to do that using Pandas dataframe? I am getting errors because of lazy loading. I cannot find a way to get around it.

Comment: I suggest you post a question about your particular case.